# 100 000+ участников в сообществе!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Сегодня на сайте появился 100 000 участник! [Ура!](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/609/alltime/ru-stackoverflow) Поздравляю всех нас!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо всем, кто активно участвует в жизни сообщества русскоязычных разработчиков! Создаваемые нами знания крайне нужны и важны всем нашим коллегам! Уверен, каждый новый участник присоединяется к сообществу с большем желанием и пониманием важности сайта!

Comment: Реально вычислить того, кто оказался стотысячным?

Comment: @alexolut Вероятно, это можно как–то сделать.

Comment: Но мы не будем, да? :) Дабы не оскорблять других участников.

Comment: @alexolut скорее всего это был "Car Rental Insurance666" %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я удалил всех страхователей заранее.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky они наверное плодятся как кролики: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/filter?search=insurance

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Готово! Этих тоже больше нет.

Comment: Партизаны, видимо, не сдаются :) - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/25105/carssales

Comment: @ViktorTomilov На самом деле, не ясно, бот ли это. Учетной записи более трех лет! Очень–очень странно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Это так называемый "пассивный упоминатель". Обратите внимание на текст его визитки "On your way from Los Angeles towards...." - с каждого ресурса по капле для гугля, yahoo и т.п. Важны не только ссылки, пассивные упоминания твоей компании также важны, и с каждым годом их доля в ссылочном рейтинге поисковиков всё  весомее.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Видим, да. Удалил из нашего сообщества, на всякий случай.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky теперь нас снова 99 999 :)

Comment: Так. Квартиру дают стотысячному зарегистрировавшемуся?

Comment: @Igor "Что нам стоит дом построить? - Нарисуем, будем жить" :)

Comment: [количество людей, которые успешно хотя бы на один вопрос в неделю отвечают](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/773714/number-of-active-experts-per-week?year=2016&week=0#graph),  сократилось в среднем [с 140 (в 2016) до 125 (в 2017)](https://gist.github.com/zed/85fc90f9be8b20d879f7f8817a7eeb5a).

Comment: @jfs Большое спасибо за анализ! Действительно, данные цифры не так радуют, как абсолютное число зарегистрированных участников. Есть над чем работать в ближайшем будущем!

Comment: @jfs Еще раз посмотрел на цифры с другой стороны. Оказалось, что, действительно, с ответами в этом году что–то пошло не так: вопросов было задано на 2.5К больше, чем дано ответов! Поиск ответов на этот вопрос и попытка улучшить ситуацию — одна из самых приоритетных задач с самого начала года!