# Когда заканчиваются "вехи"?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, мета

Недавно очередной участник ruSO перешагнул порог круглой репутации в 100 тысяч. Событие всё ещё достаточно редкое для нашего сайта, но уже далеко не первое. Вопрос-поздравление, адресованный участнику, содержит помимо метки [поздравление](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) метку [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8).

За год до этого события возник вопрос [Так когда же нужно использовать [поздравление]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10937/176217) (по стопам другого поздравления). Я тогда дал ответ и до сих пор придерживаюсь мнения, что метка [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8) может быть использована только для каких-то первых эпохальных событий, иначе смысл метки просто будет утерян в дальнейшем при неминуемом  увеличении кол-ва участников, перешагнувших знаменательный порог репутации.

Поздравление на Мете - это уже достаточно приятное событие (не только для "виновника торжества", но и для остальных активных участников сайта), но чтобы иметь ещё и метку [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8) для этого надо быть первым в причине, побудившей написать поздравительный пост.

Я безусловно рад за всех, кого поздравили на Мете с достижением репутационного порога, но предлагаю оставить метку [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8), только там, где зафиксировано первенство.

Comment: Нужно понимать, что для enSO 100k это в порядке вещей, а для ruSO это еще пока только веха.

Comment: @Sevastopol' и когда же оно закончится для ruSO по вашему мнению? 10, 20, 50, 100 участников? Собственно вопрос из заголовка.

Comment: αλεχολυτ, я не предсказатель. Бесспорно одно, пока что для ruSO это значимое событие. Разве нет?

Comment: @Sevastopol' так я не про дату, чтобы быть предсказателем, а про кол-во. Вы же говорите, что для enSO это в порядке вещей, сейчас там ~1000 участников, у которых >100k rep. Значит, число где-то в диапазоне от 7 (ruSO) до 1000 (enSO). Вот мне и интересно, где же эта граница "веха - не веха" по вашему мнению.

Comment: αλεχολυτ, в этом вся и разница, 1 000 и 7. Если у нас 1 раз в год, и это в лучшем случае, достигается 100k, то разве для нас это не веха? Это если смотреть с этой точки зрения. Всё зависит от того, как трактовать. Но если же рассматривать иначе, то веха может быть и как событие, которое произошло для нашего ресурса впервые. Нужно определить, что для ruSO в общем-то значит веха, потому что само понятие, а оно означает значимое событие, можно понимать по-разному. Я вот думаю, что для ruSO очередной 100k это пока что событие более чем значимое.

Answer (score 6):

Попробую всё же подкрепить свою точку зрения на поставленный вопрос самостоятельным ответом.

Для чего существуют метки? В первую очередь - это средство фильтрации информации, исключения "шума", ради чего задумывался Stack Overflow и вся сеть Stack Exchange.

Выбирая интересующую метку отсекается всё лишнее, вы видите только вопросы, которые хотели бы видеть. Конечно, при условии, что метка используется правильно.

При создании метки [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8) ставилась цель видеть её на вопросах, которые описывают жизненный путь "Stack Overflow на русском". Например:

- [Новая эра сообщества: теперь без беты!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1985/176217)
- [Следующий этап развития русскоязычного сообщества: сайт без выделенного управляющего](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217)
- [Четверть миллиона вопросов в русскоязычной базе знаний!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8572/176217)
- [100 000+ участников в сообществе!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6582/176217)
- [Публичная страница сообщества в ВКонтакте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759/176217)

Безусловно, таких вопросов по определению не может быть много. Метка [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8) - это редкая метка.

Название метки при этом позаимствовано со [страницы привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=milestone): вехи = milestone.

Т.о. использование метки [вехи](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b8) для поздравления очередного участника, набравшего кругленькую репутацию, я не считаю правильным. Более того, для этого уже есть метка [поздравление](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), зачем их бездумно объединять?

Ни в коем случае не хочу принизить заслуг высокореповых участников в части развития сообщества и наполнения базы знаний хорошими вопросами и ответами, но давайте всё же использовать метки правильно.

Comment: Не вопрос, давайте. Пусть только сообщество решит, что для нас будет правильное использование в данном случае метки `вехи`. Решит сообщество использовать эту метку, например, только для первого 100k и для первого 200k участников, или вовсе ее не использовать в таких случаях, то я по крайней мере со своей стороны уберу ее с последнего вопроса-поздравления. Важно не то, есть она там или нет, а важно решение сообщества. Консенсус нужен.

Comment: На мой взгляд, достижение несколькими первыми участниками высокой круглой оценки это тоже важная веха на жизненном пути сайта

Comment: @avp почему-то при этом никто не может в конкретику. Первой десятке ставим вехи, а одиннадцатый - по боку? Так он обидеться может. Он что "меньше сил потратил"?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, чтобы не было споров в дальнейшем, поставьте в этой теме на голосование. `1.` Присваивать метку `вехи` только первым 100k, 200k, 300k  и т.д. участникам. `2.` Присваивать эту метку всем участникам, достигшим 100k, 200k, 300k и т.д. `3`. В этих достижениях не присваивать метку `вехи`, а ограничиться только меткой `поздравление`. И пусть решит сообщество, это будет справедливо.

Answer (score 5):

Честно говоря, даже не обратил внимание, какая стоит метка, под поздравительным топиком.
Думаю, что и 99% процентам  людей, это тоже было бы, всё равно, в таких случаях. Важен и приятен сам факт и слова поздравления, а под какой меткой поздравили, это совсем уж всё равно.

Давайте разберемся, кому нужна и важна эта метка?
Участнику или сайту?

Если сайту, то он любит  цифры, статистику, например - 200 тыс. вопросов в год и система её считает, фиксирует. Другими словами в процессе упорядочивания базы знаний, статистики, эта метка не участвует, фиксируется сам факт  столько то людей, с такой то репутацией.

Что является в этом случае `вехой` определяет человек, на основе каких-то правил.
Цитата ТС, что для такого случая:

> метка вехи может быть использована только для каких-то первых
> эпохальных событий, иначе смысл метки просто будет утерян в дальнейшем
> при неминуемом увеличении кол-ва участников, перешагнувших
> знаменательный порог репутации.

- Хорошо, метка `вехи` первому участнику, за первые 100к
- метка `вехи` первому участнику за 200к
- и т.д

Теперь хорошо бы вернуться к реалиям:

- С репутацией 100к - 7 участников
  8, 9 участник будет не раньше чем через год, полтора
- 2-ой участник с репутацией 200к, появится не раньше, чем через
  полгода

то есть под метку `вехи` попадают всего два топика, по предлагаемой схеме, которая  касается поздравления людей и ещё пара десятков топиков со статистикой годовых цифр.
Так может быть проще не менять сложившиеся традиции присваивать метку - `вехи` за круглые, большие цифры репутации, а то возникают резонные вопросы, а чем хуже второй, третий, десятый участник, им что было легче дойти до 100к?

Для сайта всё равно, сколько людей достигло большой, круглой цифры, а вот для человека это действительно, какая-то **веха** и моральное удовлетворение, за то что он делился своими знаниями, и потратил значительное время и усилия, отвечая на вопросы.

Comment: Из текущего описания метки: "Метка для вопросов, затрагивающих ключевые этапы развития Stack Overflow на русском", т.е. в текущем виде это все таки про вехи сайта, а не человека

Comment: @yolosora Хочу заметить, что  метку создаёт один человек и её описание, как правило, это его авторское видение назначения метки. Я так понимаю, что на момент создания метки, голая статистика сайта была для создателя метки важнее всего. А люди, которые создают именно эту статистику сайта ничего не значат? У них не может быть тех самых `вех`?  Описание метки не обсуждалась, обсуждалось только правильность её применения. Я так полагаю, что после обсуждения, можно расширить описание метки.

Comment: Поэтому я и упомянул что вопросы не попадают под *текущее* описание метки. Нужно либо описание метки расширить, либо снять метку с части вопросов. Имхо, оба решения абсолютно безболезненные.

Comment: В вашем ответе достаточно противоречий. С одной стороны указываете, что наличие метки не важно для 99%, с другой стороны - это даёт моральное удовлетворение. Далее, реалии: 7 участников - мало, т.е. надо метку ставить; следом *"а чем хуже второй, третий, десятый участник, им что было легче дойти до 100к"*, т.е. число участников уже не имеет значение. Или при достижении N участников надо перестать вешать метку, а может быть даже снять её с тех постов, где её раньше поставили, для равноправия, так сказать? По самой метке, она создавалась не единолично, а путём утверждения ещё парой проверяющих.